# SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'objectstore:config'

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, persistent-object-store

The error being thrown starts with this:

org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'objectstore:config'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, e.t.c}' is expected.

i have added both, Namespace and Schema Location added in .XML

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Thank you everyone, i have solved this as below
Edit:
added
www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore  to in schema location along with http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore has to be added in schema location along with http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Did you change anything in the Configuration xml file, because above mentioned declarations comes default when you create a new flow.
Please do check.

Comment: hi i have not changed anything but added http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore to schema location because it doesnt come by default. It is working now